# How to refer a profile in maven spring boot project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am novice when it comes to maven and spring boot. I need to run a spring boot project based on the profile. By default, the scope of following dependency is `test` which throws error at run time if I want to use `h2`. As I am not allowed to change the scope, I thought of adding two profiles in `pom.xml` - one default to be active by default and one for the h2 dependency without scope as test.

Following is what I added to `pom.xml` -

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>automation</id>
            <properties>
                <env>automation</env>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Now, I tried to run my project using following command -

```
mvn -D "spring-boot.run.profiles=automation" -DskipTests=true spring-boot:run
```

But I still see the same h2 dependency scope error that I was seeing earlier.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
```

i.e. I am unable to change the scope of dependency this way. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a Maven profile, but activating a Spring profile. Use the following syntax:

`mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P profile-1,profile-2`

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

**Update**

I tested the configuration you posted, and `spring-boot:run` fails for me if only `default` profile is active with the follwoing exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
```

You can check your dependencies with

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

The output of above command varies according to maven profiles passed in.

Comment: Thanks. How do we specify a properties file to be referred in Profile? Now its works. But somehow working either ways i.e. passing the automation profile or no profile at all.  Expected it to fail for default one actually.

Comment: Inspect your maven output to check what profiles are active when no -P is passed.

Comment: It says `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`. How can I reference the properties file relative to the one in maven profile? Is it the way - `<properties>
                <env>automation</env>
            </properties>`

Comment: You may try to define your dependency in dependencies section. Use a variable in the scope. Define this variable as compile in automation profile, but test in the default profile.